# Send VBO to GPU in separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I'm working on an LWJGL game in which the world changes quite often, and because it's rather large, it causes the game to freeze for a fraction of a second every time the world and consequently the corresponding VBO is updated. I've reduced the time the game freezes for by moving all logic to a separate thread (well, it's actually the rendering code that's in a separate thread), but pushing the data to the graphics card still seems to create a noticeable delay. Is it possible to send that VBO in my logic thread so as not to slow down the game?

Additionally, if this belongs on gamedev.so, let me know so I can move it. I wasn't quite sure, so I decided to post here.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you're doing inter-thread communication? Through an Exchanger? A queue? A latch?

Comment: You are probably going to want to use a double-buffered VBO for this. You will also need two render contexts that share resources, since window systems will not let you access the same render context in more than one thread simultaneously. In your worker thread, you would (re-)allocate a VBO and upload data (or stream new data in, if the size does not change), when this operation completes signal the primary drawing thread to exchange the VBO handle used for drawing/uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to write my comment up as an answer because it differs slightly from the other two answers in the overhead on the drawing thread. Instead of stalling the pipeline when you upload your vertex data or unmap your buffer, I propose double-buffering and exchanging the VBO used for drawing with the one used for submitting data after your worker thread finishes its update.

You will need two render contexts for this approach, each of which shares resources.

In your worker thread, you can allocate/stream subdata into a VBO like you normally would in your current approach, the only difference is you will be doing this to a VBO that is not used for drawing. When you complete filling this VBO with data, let your drawing thread know and then exchange the VBO used for drawing with the VBO used for streaming vertex data when it comes time to draw. Your worker thread should block until the drawing thread swaps VBOs in this scenario.

This way, instead of stalling your drawing thread when new data has to be submitted to the GPU, you will instead stall the thread used to stream new data until the drawing thread swaps VBOs. As a result rendering will be smooth(er), but updates may occur at more variable frequency. This is generally a desirable characteristic in interactive software like games - an extra frame of latency before something new pops up is often better than a frame that takes twice as long to finish.

If you want to queue up more than one update at a time, so that your update thread does not have to block as often, I would suggest implementing a circular buffer like derhass mentioned in his answer. But it sounds like you only need a front/back buffer from your problem description.

Comment: I'm still new to more advanced OpenGL rendering methods (as opposed to display lists), so I'm not entirely sure of what you're getting at, but I think I have a decent idea. I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

<del>You can't use multitasking for rendering using OpenGL.</del> *Apparently I was wrong, though the rest of the answer is still great, if you want to fix the problem using only a single OpenGL Context.*

Though I came across the same problem when I made an *Infinite Procedural Terrain Generator*, the problem was the same as your problem, each time the world updated or generated a new *Terrain Chunk* it would freeze for just a fraction of a second.

#### How to fix this

Basically how I fixed this was by doing the following.

Create a *Thread Pool/Thread Queue*, the each time the world changes, you let a separate `Thread` process/update or recreate the `FloatBuffer` (or which other buffer you use). Since usually that is the reason for the freezing, simply because it takes a lot of time to create the buffers, input and change all the data etc.

Here is a layout of what I mean.

```
class VBOAntiFreeze {
    FloatBuffer vertex_data;
    // Just add the rest of the FloatBuffers you use as well, like FloatBuffer
    // normal_data; FloatBuffer color_data; etc.

    // You would also have all the other variables as the vbo_handle, vertices count, etc.

    boolean fresh = true;
    boolean dirty, updating;

    public void updateVBO() {
        if (fresh && !updating) {
            updating = true;

            // You could execute new Threads by creating a
            // Thread Pool/Thread Queue, that way, you will
            // have some more control over all the threads.

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Update and process all the FloatBuffers here!

                    dirty = true;
                    fresh = false;
                    updating = false;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public void renderVBO() {
        if (updating) {
            return;
        }
        else if (fresh) {
            updateVBO();

            return;
        }

        if (dirty) {
            // Buffer all the newly updated data
        }

        // Render the VBO here
    }
}
```

By using this idea you probably won't be experiencing the random freezing, unless your VBO are insanely huge, thereby the `if (dirty) buffer new data` will/can probably still freeze a little, though I've never experienced that before. *But just saying, to inform you!*

Comment: You *can* do multi-threaded rendering in OpenGL, but you need assistance from the underlying window system in order to create a shared context for each thread. And depending on the desired application, you may also need things like fence sync objects.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that, but thanks for telling me, I fixed the answer, the rest of the answer is still a good idea when only using a single OpenGL context.

Comment: At the moment, my code already partially implements this. VBO creation is handled in the logic thread (the main thread), while VBO allocation (which is what I'm having trouble with) is done in the graphics thread.

Comment: Well the code works in the way, where the rendering and binding of buffers is done by the graphics thread, and the generating/updating of the FloatBuffers or in other words the VBO allocation, is done by a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a GL context can be current to a single thread at any time, and a thread can have one current GL context at any time. If you want to do parallel updates of GL objects, you have two options:

1. Use shared contexts. That way, each trhead can have its own GL context, but the objects like buffers textures, ... can be used (and modified) by both threads.
2. For your particular scenario. it might be enough to use (maybe a ring buffer of) mapped VBOs. You need the GL context only to map/unmap the buffer, but while it is mapped, you can access it in arbitrary threads - which don't need a GL context at all. Usually, a ring buffer of VBOs is used in such a scenario to avoid excessive synchronisation between the threads.

Comment: Excellent point about mapping circular buffers in a single render context. But wouldn't the process of unmapping the buffer (since this has to be done in the drawing thread) introduce about the same amount of synchronization overhead as some alternative approaches? I don't think he's queuing up more than one update at a time in this scenario.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Well, I would recommend using 3 buffers: one with the current data used for rendering, one in the process of beeing updated (or wating to be filled) and one "spare". Note that the synchronization for the unmap point is quite uncritical, the render thread never has to wait, but just to check if a new buffer is ready, and can unmap and use it spot on. OTOH, the map operation itself can be critical, as the GL might still use the buffer and one is forcing a synchronisation with the GL by mapping it, so the third buffer can be used to delay the map by another frame or so.